# Is there a regex pattern to remove all numbers preceding every "<" in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

While I've utilized simple regex patterns for things like form validation and small string edits, this snippet has proven to be more challenging than my other tasks.
My current patterns perform a number of functions including adding line breaks at specific points.

```
...().replace(/^.\s+|\s+$/gm, '').replace(/>/g, ">\r").replace(/(.{99})/g, "$1\r"));


1<div class="form-group stacked" aria-live="polite" id="test-input">
2<label for="company">
3Business name4<sup>
5*6</sup>
7</label>
8<div class="input-wrapper is-clear">
9<input type="text" class="form-control stacked has-clear" id="company" name="company" required="" 
aria-required="true" value="">
10</input>
11<button class="btn clear-field-button" type="button" tabindex="0" style="display: inline-block;" 
aria-label="Clear Business name input field">
12<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 22.673 22.674">...
```

Should render as

```
<div class="form-group stacked" aria-live="polite" id="test-input">
<label for="company">
3Business name<sup>
5*</sup>
</label>
<div class="input-wrapper is-clear">
<input type="text" class="form-control stacked has-clear" id="company" name="company" required="" 
aria-required="true" value="">
</input>
<button class="btn clear-field-button" type="button" tabindex="0" style="display: inline-block;" 
aria-label="Clear Business name input field">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 22.673 22.674">...
```

Any guidance and/or solutioning is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Consider an html parser

Comment: Not sure what current regexs are doing/trying to do. If that is to remove number before less than you should swap to `\d+<` and replace with `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, look at [character classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Character_classes).  The simplest way is to use "\d+"  which is the same as "[0-9]+" followed by the literal "<" as suggested to you by user3783243 in the comment.

```js
const before = document.getElementById("before");
const after = document.getElementById("after");

const page = `1<div class="form-group stacked" aria-live="polite" id="test-input">
2<label for="company">
3Business name4<sup>
5*6</sup>
7</label>
8<div class="input-wrapper is-clear">
9<input type="text" class="form-control stacked has-clear" id="company" name="company" required="" 
aria-required="true" value="">
10</input>
11<button class="btn clear-field-button" type="button" tabindex="0" style="display: inline-block;" 
aria-label="Clear Business name input field">
12<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 22.673 22.674">`;

before.value = page;
after.value = page.replaceAll(/\d+</g, '<');
```

```html
<h2>Before</h2>
<textarea id="before" rows="15" cols="80"></textarea>
<h2>After</h2>
<textarea id="after" rows="15" cols="80"> </textarea>
```